# Compare sum of two columns to one column

Tags: mysql, aggregate

I am trying to compare the sum of two column values to a third column values, then display a string literal as result set value. Here's my query

Here's my schema with sample data

```
Player_Games
------------------------
Game1 | Game 2 | Game 3
------------------------
 20   |   13   |    45
------------------------
 14   |   27   |    25
------------------------
 18   |   17   |    36
------------------------
 20   |   20   |    29
------------------------
 32   |   10   |    33
------------------------

SELECT 
CASE
    WHEN((
        SELECT SUM(Game1 + Game2) as total FROM Player_Games
        ) 
        < 
        (
        SELECT Game3 FROM Player_Games
        ))
         THEN "Expected_Performance"
END as Result
```

FROM Player_Games;

**Expected Result**

```
Expected Performance
NULL
Expected Performance
NULL
NULL
```

However, an error is thrown `ERROR 1242 (21000) at line 4: Subquery returns more than 1 row`

What am I missing here? Do I need to `GROUP BY Game3?`

Comment: *compare the sum of two column values to a third column values* - third column value of what row?

Comment: How many rows are ```SELECT Game3 FROM Player_Games``` returned?

Comment: please add sample data and show what you try to do. this error is normal if you have more than one row inside player games table ...

Comment: @AliFidanli I should have clarifying my question better. I do have more than one row inside player games table. I basically want this query to check every row, and see if Game1 + Game 2 < Game 3, display "Expected Performance" In result set

Comment: @过过招 `SELECT Game3 FROM Player_Games` returns 5 rows. It has same amount of rows as `Game1` and `Game2`

Comment: @Akina err.. of every row? For each row, I want the result set to display `Expected Performance` if the sum of Game1 + Game2 < Game3. I updated my question to be more clear hopefully.

Comment: You don't have player `ID` or `name` on the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you dont need sum here. just case :

```
    SELECT 
    CASE
        WHEN Game1 + Game2 < Game3
             THEN 'Expected_Performance'
    END as Result
FROM Player_Games
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just check using a `CASE` expression whether the sum of game1 and game2 is less than game3 then add the needed text.

**Query**

```
select 
case when game1 + game2 < game3
   then 'Expected performance' 
   else null end as result
from player_games;
```

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT CASE WHEN t1.Game3 > t2.total THEN "Expected_Performance" END
FROM Player_Games t1
CROSS JOIN (SELECT SUM(Game1 + Game2) as total FROM Player_Games) t2
```

On 8+

```
SELECT CASE WHEN Game3 > SUM(Game1 + Game2) OVER () THEN "Expected_Performance" END
FROM Player_Games
```

---

If you need to summarize not over whole table but only in single row then

```sql
SELECT CASE WHEN Game3 > Game1 + Game2 THEN "Expected_Performance" END
FROM Player_Games
```

---

PS. There is no guarantee that the output rows order matches the source one (in all queries). So you must add some column into the output list which identifies separate rows.

Comment: Why 2 `totals`?

Comment: @RickJames Misprint, fixed. Thanks.